# I am enqueuing stylesheet main while my images are not showing

Tags: html, wordpress, subdirectory, enqueue

I am converting HTML to Wordpress theme. I am enqueuing stylesheet. but some of the images are not showing. 
Maybe its  could be subfolder issue

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, you might want to provide some code snippets to give us a better picture of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly a pathing issue -- without being able to see any of your file structure or code, I suspect get_template_directory_uri() is the missing piece.  Here's a simplified example of what you need to do.

```
function itc_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'itc_wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

You should replace itc_ with your own prefix on the function name.

Comment: I like your answer but the only problem I am facing is missing images while enqueuing. is that any specific way to load images